# Cities translating on different languages

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, react-i18next

I have a cities list of all countries and I want to translate it to different languages. Is there some library such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n-iso-countries? I tried to search it, but didn't find anything. Would be glad if someone knows some easy way to translate cities of all countries, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good database with translations https://github.com/x88/i18nGeoNamesDB, that my friend sent me